# Inserting/Deleting into UITableView with NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, swift

I'm relatively new to Swift development and I'm struggling with updating a UITableView with a new entity (CoreData) when using NSFetchedResultsController.

I've searched around on the internet and followed various tutorials, but despite following them, when I convert it to my situation something is going amiss and after numerous hours scratching my head over it, I can't seem to see what is wrong.

I wish to store the data in a tableView, allow swiping left for deletion and have a form for creating new data for the table.  I've had the insertion working, but not the deletion and now have the deletion working, but not the insertion.

I have variables for context and collect my data like so:

```
func loadData() {
    let request = MyData.fetchRequest() as NSFetchRequest<MyData>
    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(MyData.name), ascending: true)
    request.sortDescriptors = [sort]

    do {
        myResults = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: #keyPath(MyData.name), cacheName: nil)
        try myResults.performFetch()

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
    myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

I'm trying to add data (when the user taps a button) like so:

```
let newData = MyData(entity: MyData.entity(), insertInto: context)
                newData.name = newName
                newData.colour = Int16(newDataPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0))
                newData.dataID = dataID
appDelegate.saveContext()
loadData()
```

And this worked without a problem, but every time I tried to delete, I would get a crash with the model data and the TableView out of synch. After a lot of research, I've implemented the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, as so:

```
extension ViewController: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
    func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        self.myTableView.beginUpdates()
    }
    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
        switch type {
        case .delete:
            self.myTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath! as IndexPath], with: .fade)
//        case .insert:
//            self.myTableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath! as IndexPath], with: .fade)
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        self.myTableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

Which now allows me delete beautifully.  Unfortunately, I now can't add as this crashes my app with the `Invalid update` error.

I've tried using the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate to work for inserts as well, with `context.insert()` but that causes a crash as well.

Please could someone let me know what stupid mistake I'm making? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are performing too many unnecessary steps which confuses the functionality of `NSFetchedResultsController`.

After deleting and inserting records the controller updates the UI automatically right after saving the context

First of all create **one** instance of `NSFetchedResultsController` as lazy instantiated property as suggested in the CoreData template and set the delegate.

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<MyData> = {

    let request = MyData.fetchRequest() as NSFetchRequest<MyData>
    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(MyData.name), ascending: true)
    request.sortDescriptors = [sort]
    let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: #keyPath(MyData.name), cacheName: nil)
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    do {
        try aFetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    return aFetchedResultsController
}()
```

Replace `loadData` with

```
func loadData()
{
    do {
        try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        tableView.reloadData()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

And implement all types in the `didChange` method

```
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
    switch type {
    case .insert: tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .fade)
    case .delete: tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .fade)
    case .update: tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .automatic)
    case .move: tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath!, to: newIndexPath!)
    @unknown default:
        fatalError("New case in controller:didChange:at:for:")
    }
}
```

If the controller is supposed to manage also sections implement

```
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atSectionIndex sectionIndex: Int, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {

    switch type {
    case .insert: tableView.insertSections(IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex), with: .automatic)
    case .delete: tableView.deleteSections(IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex), with: .fade)
    default: return
    }
}
```

Now insert a record into the context or remove a record from the context. Then save the context – nothing else – and the fetch results controller does the rest. Don't call `loadData` nor reload the table view additionally.